# Django. Create custom object without save and return like a queryset

Tags: python, django

I need create empty objects without save in data base(like a custom object for a specific conditions) and add this object to queryset.

I have wtritten code:

```
# create empty queryset

    queryset = MajorMinor.objects.none()


            major_minor = MajorMinor.objects.model
            dealer = User.objects.model
            dealer.email = 'test@gmail.com'

            grower = User.objects.model
            grower.email = 'test@gmail.com'

            major_minor.major = dealer
            major_minor.minor = grower
             # add my obj to queryset
            queryset |= major_minor
            return queryset
```

but i have had an error:

```
type object 'MajorMinor' has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: First, Django models are just python classes, so you instantiate them like any other python object: `major_minor = MajorMinor()` or `dealer = User()`. Second, you can't add objects to a QuerySet, a queryset is a **potential** query that may not have been evaluated yet. First evaluate your Queryset, cast it to a **list** and then add your instances to the list.

Comment: @dirkgroten so add empty obj with a "custom data" to a queryset is inpossible?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible. You should tell us what you're really trying to achieve, this sounds like an XY problem: your real problem is something else, you're trying to solve it this way, but that's not the right way to approach it.

Comment: @dirkgroten i have a some specific task. If from mobile i will have "specific" request i need return 1 object in a list, and this object must contains some data. For my task i need return `MajorMinor` object in a list with a test data. Lets imagining you need return one user(without create in data base) with a some test data in user list, how you will do it? I can't solve my problem

Comment: Just return the object in a list, I don't understand why you need to return a queryset. In fact, you never return a queryset, a queryset gets evaluated at some stage and when rendered, it "becomes" a list of objects.

Comment: @dirkgroten are you mean like this? -> `return list(major_minor)`

Comment: No, that's **casting** to a list. Please learn some python by doing a good course before embarking on a django project. `[a, b, c]` is how you construct a list with objects `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: @dirkgroten oh, i understood. I thought `[]` -> array, `list()` -> list. So, i have trited `return [major_minor]` but i have recived an error `'list' object has no attribute 'model'`

Comment: You need to explain where you are using this returned value.